# Cosine similarity of rows in a data frame

Tags: r, data-analysis, analysis, cosine-similarity

I have a data set where each column has a probabilty for different parameters of a given object. The first column is a string indicating the object name while all the other columns have a numeric value.

I am using the cosine() function from the 'coop' package to find the cosine similarity between the objects. Ideally I want the function to interpret each row as an individual vector and give me an individual cosine similarity between each object. However much I've tried I have not be able to do this as the function does not accept a string value (object name) as an input.

For simplicity's sake let's say my data looks like this (in reality it's much bigger and complex):

abc  0.75   0.23

xyz   0.80  0.40

jkl       0.32  0.91

The end result I need would be a 3x3 matrix that compares abc,xyz and jkl using the numerical values.

Pretty sure I'm missing something very simple here but I would appreciate any kind of help. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to generate the 3x3 matrix you want.

```
library(coop)
df = data.frame(name=c('abc', 'xyz', 'jkl'), v1=c(0.75,0.8,0.32), v2 = c(0.23,0.4, 0.91))

# make a matrix transposed with each column corresponding to the name
mm = t(as.matrix(df[,2:3]))
cosine(mm)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.9862394 0.5937443
#[2,] 0.9862394 1.0000000 0.7186021
#[3,] 0.5937443 0.7186021 1.0000000
```